# vscode file explorer won't auto refresh

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VsCode, if I create/delete/change files, the file explorer won't update accordingly. It was working perfect until a couple of weeks ago, but suddenly it stoped and updates only if I manually click the refresh button. I uploaded a quick 20 seconds video to youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCv1Nh_Ae24) to better explain the problem.

This is my VsCode version information:

```
Version: 1.57.1
Commit: 507ce72a4466fbb27b715c3722558bb15afa9f48
Date: 2021-06-17T13:26:50.042Z
Electron: 12.0.7
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 20.5.0
```

I'm on macoS Big Sur 11.4 (20F71), and VsCode is opened in my git root repository.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: This issue in Github is sort of similar: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125886 - Try the [Insiders Edition of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and see if it behaves the same - I believe they fixed whatever the issue was in the link I posted and have pushed it to the Insiders Edition so far.

Answer (score 0):

## Not the expected solution

Some days ago, I created a second user for my Mac to use it for work, and I set it as admin with all privileges, equal to my first and main account. At first, I didn't think this had any relation at all, but in my main account in another random project I ran `make` command and I literally got an error message saying that I didn't have authorization to run `make` there. It made no sense because I did it a couple of weeks ago perfectly, curiously when the new user didn't yet exist.

This made me realize that I somehow screwed up things with this new user, and as an ex-windows user, my solution was simple: hard-factory-reset my Mac. And now, it works like a charm!

Obs.: I tried deleting the new User and also reinstalling vscode, but it didn't solve the problem, only after my hard reset.